# SQL QUERY to display a 2 columns table in one column with some conditions

Tags: sql

```
A  1  
A  2   
A  3  
B  4  
B  5  
C  6
```

this is my table having 2 columns the letters and the numbers, i need to display it like this, to only display distinct columns from column 1:

```
A
1
2
3
B
4
B
5
C
6
```

Comment: Why `B` twice?  Easy enough to get your results with a `union` though...

Comment: Your desired output has B listed twice. Do you want distinct (unique) values?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do has two issues:

- First, the first column looks like a string and the second like a number.  A single column can have only one type.
- Second, SQL result sets and tables represent unordered sets (unless you use an `order by`).

These are two reasons why this type of manipulation is more typically done at the application level.

But you can do it.  Here is one method that works in practice:

```
select 'A' union all
select col2 from t where col1 = 'A' union all
select 'B' union all
select col2 from t where col1 = 'B' union all
select 'C' union all
select col2 from t where col1 = 'C';
```

The resulting column with be a string.

Note:  `union all` does not guarantee the ordering of the results (although it is correct in practice).  A more correct version is:

```
select col
from (select 'A' as col, 1 as priority union all
      select col2, 2 from t where col1 = 'A' union all
      select 'B', 3 union all
      select col2, 4 from t where col1 = 'B' union all
      select 'C', 5 union all
      select col2, 6 from t where col1 = 'C'
     ) t
order by priority;
```